# Iterate and modify python dictionary values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm having a Python Dictionary with input values as following

`{'172.16.50.30': '5022', '172.16.50.31': '5006', '172.16.50.33': '5003', '172.16.50.34': '5018', '172.16.50.35': '5019', ......}`

I want to map last octet of my IP addresses instead of the actual one. I want to get rid of my First 3 octet of IP addresses(172.16.50.*). My desired output should be like following and without any Quotes

`{ 30: 5022, 31: 5006, 33: 5003, 34: 5018, 35: 5019 .........}`

What should be the ideal way to implement this ?

Comment: What do you want to do with `{'172.16.50.30': '5022', '172.17.50.30': '5003'}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a dictionary comprehension:

```
{k.rsplit('.', 1)[-1]:v for k,v in d.items()}
# {'30': '5022', '31': '5006', '33': '5003', '34': '5018', '35': '5019'}
```

---

If you want integer types as your answer suggests:

```
{int(k.rsplit('.', 1)[-1]):int(v) for k,v in d.items()}
# {30: 5022, 31: 5006, 33: 5003, 34: 5018, 35: 5019}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's "the best" way to do it but this does the job.

```
 d1 = {'172.16.50.30': '5022', '172.16.50.31': '5006', '172.16.50.33': '5003'}
 d2 ={}
 for key, val in d1.items():
    d2[key.split('.')[3]] = val
```